# A task on rails that I need to get all information from models of a student

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am starter to rails.
I want to do a task on rails that...
" A student having his personal information like firstname, lastname, fathername, age, sex,address" in one table
and, also having "individual marks of subject, toatl marks, grade" in another table.

My intention is that..I need to get all information about a student when I click on student name on view. this whole I need to done using scaffold.

I had created two models for those two tables using scaffold.
May I need to create one more table for getting total marks for individual subject marks.
How can I associate those models and How can I create a link for student name and student id in view.

Please help me to crack this...
Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot going on here, so I'm not going to answer everything. I will point you in the right direction though.

For model associations, you're going to use [ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). These look like:

```
MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things
end
```

For creating the links in the views, read up on [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) first to get an idea of what REST is and then [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html). You will have helpers in your views that look like:

```
link_to "Something", my_model_path(@my_model)
```